# Angular 7 Reactive Forms : Issue in reseting validators and whole form contains

Tags: angular, reset, angular-reactive-forms

I want to submit and reset a form after validation .

validation and submition and init of inputs values works good, but validators won't be reseted.

here is the result after form submittion

[image]

Register the control in the template :

```html
    <form [formGroup]="createSeanceForm" #formDirective="ngForm"  class="needs-validation" (ngSubmit)="createSeance(createSeanceForm, formDirective)">
```

My input and how i show errors :

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 ">
       <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
            'has-success': (submitted  || f.date.touched || f.date.dirty) &&  f.date.valid ,
            'has-danger': (submitted || f.date.touched || f.date.dirty) &&  f.date.invalid
                                                                        }">
           <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" formControlName="date" placeholder="Date de la visite">
       </div>

     <div *ngIf="submitted && f.date.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
       <small class="text-danger ml-3 my-1" *ngIf="f.date.errors.required">Merci de renseigner ce champ !</small>

    </div>
```

My imports :

```js
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
```

My constructor and formGroup declaration:

```js
createSeanceForm: FormGroup;

    constructor( 
    ...
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
        ) { 
           
           
          this.initSeanceForm();

        }
```

My InitForm :

```js
initSeanceForm() {
    this.createSeanceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    date: ['', Validators.required],
    act: ['', Validators.required],
    doctor: ['', [Validators.required]],
    price: ['',],
    teeth: ['',]
    //teeth: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
  }

  get f() { return this.createSeanceForm.controls; }
```

Submit and reset Function

```js
 createSeance(myForm, formDirective: FormGroupDirective){    

      this.submitted = true;
        
      // stop here if form is invalid
      if (this.createSeanceForm.invalid) {
          return;
      }else{
     TODO : API stuff.

       formDirective.resetForm();
       this.createSeanceForm.reset();
       this.createSeanceForm.markAsPristine();
       this.createSeanceForm.markAsUntouched();

        $('#addSeanceModal').modal('hide')
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove validation from the controls? Or do you want to hide the validation messages when the form gets resetted?

Comment: yes, why the errors messages are dispayed before  touching or submiting the form for the second time.
NB : the first submition  action is ok : it control inputs and submit data, after first submition it shows errors

Comment: Actually, you want to remove the validators once the form is submitted.?

Comment: Exactly, to not affect other submit action